# Why do my camera child nodes not appear?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skcameranode

I have a camera node that follows the player but when the player moves my hud moves offscreen. After doing some research I found that they won't move if I make them a child of the camera but with I implement the following code my hud completely disappears. I tried making the zPosition and size very large so I couldn't miss them if they were there. But even then they are still not visible.

```
self.camera = cam

cam.addChild(dpadButton)
dpadButton.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
dpadButton.zPosition = 1000
dpadButton.size = CGSize(width: 4000, height: 4000)
dpadButton.xScale = 1
dpadButton.yScale = 1.3
dpadButton.name = "DpadButton"
dpadButton.alpha = 1
```

Also when I have self.addChild(dpadButton) 8 nodes appear at the bottom right but when I have cam.addChild(dpadButton) only 7 appear.

Comment: 4000 is huge for a dpad,  the 1.3 scale is also probably throwing it off,  not sure why you need to deal in such large numbers

Comment: I was just trying to make it huge to make sure it wasn't off screen somewhere and I was missing it somehow

Comment: did you ever add the camera to the scene?

Comment: Nope I actually figured that out this morning and it fixed it! but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to actually add the camera node to the scene with self.addChild(cam) thanks @KnightOfDragon for helping